# How do I get a Cognito token within a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am trying to get a Cognito access token from a lambda function. The lambda function is acting as a middleman to transfer requests from an IOT device to my own API. In order for the API to accept the request, my lambda function needs to send a valid Cognito access token to the API.

I understand how to send the token using the Authorization header, but what I don't understand is how to receive a token without requiring a user to log in. IE I want serverless authentication. My research has revealed several options. Recently, I tried using a client credentials grant from Cognito's token endpoint, but despite my app client id and secret key being correct for the user pool I'm using, Cognito says my client is invalid.

Has anyone done something like this before? If so, what method did you use? Thanks!

Comment: Your sample code might help in understanding your problem.

Comment: I solved the problem by using the warrant library found here: https://github.com/capless/warrant which makes accessing Cognito much simpler in python (which I used in my lambda function). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

one option is to use the warrant library found here: https://github.com/capless/warrant. I was able to access Cognito with Python much easier than the boto3 library.